# Find the number of ways in which $5$ subjects can be arranged if each subject is allotted at least one period and no period remains vacant.

Tags: combinatorics

There are six periods in each working day of a school.  Find the number of ways in which $5$ subjects can be arranged if each subject is allotted at least one period and no period remains vacant.

---

Let $P_1,P_2,....,P_6$ be the periods and $S_1,S_2,....,S_5$ be the subjects.
$5$ subjects can be arranged in $5!$ ways.
 
Out of $S_1,S_2,....,S_5$,one can be chosen in $5$ ways and out of $P_1,P_2,....,P_6$,one can be chosen in $6$ ways,so the remaining can be arranged in $5\times 6=30 $ ways.So total$=30\times 5!=3600$ ways.
But my answer is not matching book answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since six periods are filled by five subjects, one of the subjects must be repeated.  There are five ways to choose the subject that is repeated.  There are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways of selecting the two periods in which that subject meets.  The remaining subjects can be placed in the four remaining periods in $4!$ ways.  Hence, the number of possible schedules is 
$$5 \cdot \binom{6}{2} \cdot 4! = 1800$$